# Relationship Diagram / Schema with selected tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms-2005

I am wondering how on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2005 can i create a relationship schema with selected tables i am using on a certain part of a website i have built. I want to see what fields they have and how they are connected.

Comment: In your database you have Database Diagrams - you can create a new ERD from there by right clicking -> New Database Diagram

Comment: Why was this tagged with "mysql"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Darren posted you go to your Database (I will post a graphical version here):

[image]

Then right click and select New Database Diagram

[image]

And then select the tables that you want to Add (I shall add two here):

[image]

And if there is no relationship yet you could drag from the Primary Key of another table to the Foreign Key of the related table:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome @AndyKirkpatrick. GOD bless your quest for learning SQL server and its tools.